# How to Display value of dynamically created varible using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

My HTML template code is:

```
<p>{{"fieldname_"+lang}}</p>
```

In the controller I have the following:

```
$scope.lang = "mr";
$scope.fieldname_mr = "Dynamic varible";
```

I want the result to be `Dynamic varible`, but it is `fieldname_mr`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: try {{fieldname_mr}}

Comment: Yes i got. But I want dynamically.

Comment: @AnitaPatil were you able to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to achieve this:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('testController',
  function testController($scope) {
   $scope.lang = "mr";   
   $scope.dynamicVars = {fieldname_mr : "Dynamic varible"};

});
```

```html
<body ng-app="app">
<div class="table-responsive" ng-controller="testController">
    {{dynamicVars["fieldname_" + lang]}}
</div>
</body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i think this solution first, ;)

Answer (score 0):

that you wnt is not able, [i made a middleware](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/15389/) solution that mantains all your needed but passed by a function that made the return of var, understand that angular force to made like this

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <span ng-init="">{{getValue('fieldname_'+lang)}}</span>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);



function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.lang = "mr"; $scope.fieldname_mr = "Dynamic varible";
    $scope.getValue =function(name){
        return $scope[name] ||'no existe man';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it like you set your **dynamic variable** in angular as follow:

what you want **variable name** store in **variable** than follow code:

```
$scope[dynamic_var]=Value of variable;
```

when you fetch this value as like:

Use this when you not fix property of scope
`alert($scope[dynamic_var])` 
use when you have fix property name
 `alert($scope.dynamic_var)`